# MySQL - trying to reorganize partition and getting error

Tags: mysql, partition

Hopefully quite simple, and probably obvious, but what is wrong with my syntax. I've been wrestling with this all morning.

I created a set of partitions thus:

```
ALTER TABLE `schemaName`.`tableName` 
PARTITION BY RANGE (TO_DAYS(`Created`)) ( 
PARTITION `early` VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DAYS('2013-01-01 00:00:00')), 
PARTITION `201301` VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DAYS('2013-02-01 00:00:00')), 
PARTITION `201302` VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DAYS('2013-03-01 00:00:00')), 
PARTITION `201303` VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DAYS('2013-04-01 00:00:00')), 
PARTITION `201304` VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE 
);
```

So far so good, the last partition now holds data for anything after 1st April (e.g. April and May).

Now I want to reorganize that partition (201304) so that it holds data for just April, and the data for May is moved into a new 'last' partition. My syntax is:

```
ALTER TABLE `schemaName`.`tableName` REORGANIZE PARTITION `201304` INTO 
( 
`201304` VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DAYS('2013-05-01 00:00:00')), 
`201305` VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE 
);
```

But I get an error which suggests the issue is at the first definition ( 201304` VALUES LESS . . . )

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`201304` VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DAYS('2013-05-01 00:00:00')),
#-->ALL DATA BEFORE ' at line 3
```

If anyone can spot the error I would be very grateful.

Comment: Try without your comment: `#-->ALL DATA BEFORE`

Comment: try without the ticks `\``

Comment: cheers,but no luck. removing the comment made no difference, and removing the ticks, just pushed the error back back to the initial partition name.

Answer (score 7):

Having scoured the internet for an example, I eventually found an example in an old book I had:

```
ALTER TABLE `schemaName`.`tableName` REORGANIZE PARTITION `201304` INTO 
( 
PARTITION `201304` VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DAYS('2013-05-01 00:00:00')), 
PARTITION `201305` VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE 
);
```